# how to use on instead of live in below

Tags: jquery

how shoul I use  on instead of live

```
$("#screen_tutorial_input_action_save")
.live(
    "click",
    function(event) {
      $(this).off(event);
      var editIndex = $(this).attr("editIndex");
      if (typeof editIndex == "undefined"
        || editIndex == "") {
          editIndex = -1;
        }

      var TutorialDataTemplate = FinalCmsData["response-content"][pageScreen].Json_Data;
      var TutorialTemplate = {
        "Name" : "$300 Cash - New Player Bonus",
"Description" : "At Winners we believe your loayality should be rewarded. Thats why we created our winners rewards Programs\r\n\r\nQuite Simply the more you bet with us the more you back in rewards.A  simple concept,but something we think is very important to make our customers feel valued.\r\n\r\nWhy Join?\r\nHere are just a few reasons to join our rewards program:\r\n-Free to join, it costs nothing\r\n-You will earn Winners Rewards points to every dollar wagered\r\n-No minimum\r\n-Reward points can be  used to wager for handicap",
"Image" : "20131202041703_1_blue.png",
"URL" : ""
      };

      TutorialDataTemplate.id = $(
        "#screen_tutorial_id").val();
      TutorialDataTemplate.logo = $(
        "#screen_tutorial_logo").val();
      TutorialDataTemplate.name = $(
          "#screen_tutorial_name").val();
      TutorialDataTemplate.title = $(
          "#screen_tutorial_title").val();

      TutorialTemplate.Name = $(
          "#screen_tutorial_input_name")
        .val();
      TutorialTemplate.Description = $(
          "#screen_tutorial_input_description")
        .val();
      TutorialTemplate.Image = $(
          "#screen_tutorial_input_file")
        .val();
      TutorialTemplate.URL = baseServerUrl
        + fileDownloadUrl
        + $("#screen_tutorial_input_file")
        .val() + "?downloadType=attached";
      if (editIndex == -1) {
        TutorialDataTemplate.AndroidTutorial
          .push(TutorialTemplate);
      } else {
        TutorialDataTemplate.AndroidTutorial[editIndex] = TutorialTemplate;
      }

      ScreenHelper.UpdateScreen("AndroidTutorial",
          TutorialDataTemplate, function(
            responseObject) {
              // Refresh View
              loadTemplate(pageId,
                "mywinners-body .sec03");
            });

      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so

```
$(document).on('click', '#screen_tutorial_input_action_save', function(event) {

});
```

or instead `document` you can use parent element which exists on your page.

[Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)